# Android SDK External Store, File Not Found

Tags: java, android, ioexception, android-external-storage

I've been struggling with storing an ArrayList on the SD card of an Galaxy S4. For reasons that I can't seem to figure out on my own, i keep getting File Not Found Exception in this piece of code:

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), name);

        if(file.exists()) file.delete();
        try{                   
                OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(file);
                OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(os);
                for(int j = 0; j < fallList.size(); j++)
                osw.write(fallList.get(j));
                os.close();
                osw.close();

            } catch (FileNotFoundException e){

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"File Not Found",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

EDIT:

After properly adding permissions i no longer get File Not Found Exception, but instead IOException. I noticed some system errors in the device monitor:

*04-26 13:54:15.115: D/ViewRootImpl(27953): ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN
04-26 13:54:20.130: D/ViewRootImpl(27953): ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN
04-26 13:54:20.270: W/System.err(27953): java.io.IOException: File descriptor closed
04-26 13:54:20.280: W/System.err(27953):    at libcore.io.Posix.writeBytes(Native Method)
04-26 13:54:20.310: W/System.err(27953):    at libcore.io.Posix.write(Posix.java:223)
04-26 13:54:20.310: W/System.err(27953):    at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.write(BlockGuardOs.java:313)
04-26 13:54:20.310: W/System.err(27953):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.write(IoBridge.java:497)
04-26 13:54:20.310: W/System.err(27953):    at java.io.FileOutputStream.write(FileOutputStream.java:186)
04-26 13:54:20.310: W/System.err(27953):    at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.flushBytes(OutputStreamWriter.java:167)
04-26 13:54:20.310: W/System.err(27953):    at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.close(OutputStreamWriter.java:140)
04-26 13:54:20.310: W/System.err(27953):    at com.example.med603.sharedpreffalldetect.MainActivity.toFile(MainActivity.java:142)
04-26 13:54:20.310: W/System.err(27953):    at com.example.med603.sharedpreffalldetect.MainActivity.access$000(MainActivity.java:35)
04-26 13:54:20.310: W/System.err(27953):    at com.example.med603.sharedpreffalldetect.MainActivity$2.onClick(MainActivity.java:73)
04-26 13:54:20.310: W/System.err(27953):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5197)
04-26 13:54:20.310: W/System.err(27953):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:20926)
04-26 13:54:20.310: W/System.err(27953):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
04-26 13:54:20.310: W/System.err(27953):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
04-26 13:54:20.310: W/System.err(27953):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
04-26 13:54:20.310: W/System.err(27953):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5951)
04-26 13:54:20.320: W/System.err(27953):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
04-26 13:54:20.320: W/System.err(27953):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
04-26 13:54:20.320: W/System.err(27953):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1400)
04-26 13:54:20.320: W/System.err(27953):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1195)*

I haven't used d.log before, so I'm not entirely sure what I'm looking at here.

Comment: `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` will never guarantee that this will return your sdcard path. Check for externally mounted storage. Read more here http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal

Comment: You need the `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission to write there. If you think that you have that set up properly, [this blog post of mine](https://commonsware.com/blog/2015/08/31/hey-where-did-my-permission-go.html) outlines some common reasons why you might still not have this permission. You might also consider editing your question and posting the Java stack trace that you should be seeing in LogCat.

Comment: Thanks for the links guys. I'll check em out.
I'll see about posting the Java stack trace afterwards!

Answer (score 0):

1. Check your permissions in AndroidManifest.xml. You need READ & WRITE permission for external storage.
2. Try to use different directory. For example, [getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStoragePublicDirectory%28java.lang.String%29)

Comment: Thanks for the swift response. I do have permissions in the manifest, both for reading and writing, and at first i tried storing the data in Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS - also getting file not found exception.

Answer (score 0):

So I figured it out; Firstly I forgot permissions when I "re-did" the application (The first try got too messy) - this solved the File Not Found Exception!

I then got an IOException which appears to be because I wasn't flushing the OutputStreamWriter.